# how to switch between layout at runtime in android?

Tags: java, android, components

i have four images in a row at the top , on click of each icon i want to change the underlaying background (image) and the controls on the layout , this way it achieves tab like structure and behavior , i want to know whats the best way to achieve this ? I think i will have four layouts each layout having one image highlighted showing that tab selected and corresponding components on layout, and will change this layout when user clicks on image.

Is this a good idea to achieve this ? or i have different solution available ?

its nice if u give me some idea about necessary features or API or layout component related code
Suggestions are welcome thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can change layouts by switching views to invisible and visible. but it's not a good idea when you want to change 4 layouts.

1. It becomes hard to maintain the code if you have 4 layouts switching.
2. It's better to use Tabs which will help you in preserving the state of the each layout.
3. Customize the tabWidget to make it look like you have 4 buttons on the top, not the tabs.

HTH.

Comment: there is hardly one or two buttons on each layout , so no issue of maintainance

Comment: also there is nothing to maintain state so i need simple solution please

Comment: then you can use switching the layouts by turning visibility on and off.

Answer (score 1):

That is not a good idea. You should use android's tab architecture. [Here is a example at developer.android](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-tabwidget.html)